# Linebreaks for long number by using siunitx-numberformat and overline

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx

Is it possible, to get for a very long decimal number linebreaks in a grouped way (see "Target")?

I need the overline-command for the "periodic part" of the number.

I would like to use the 1000sep from siunitx.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = \text{\,}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\List{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,111}{%
\global\edef\List{\List\i}}

\section{Actual}
My very long Number: $0,\, 555\, \overline{\num{\List}}$

\section{Target}
$\begin{array}{l l l}
0, & 555 & \overline{\num{123456789101112131415161718192021
222324252627282930313233}} \\
& & \overline{\num{3435363738394041424344454647484950
51525354555657585960}\dots} \\
& & \vdots \\
& & \overline{\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\num{110111}}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What information are you trying to convey to your readers by showing a string 333 digits, grouped into 111 separate parts of 3?

Comment: I had to conjure up an arbitrary example.

Comment: Or do you mean the need for the 1000Sep? I want to make the number manageable and easy to read.